# Which version of my site is preferable for SEO

Tags: seo, performance, page-speed

As you can see from the graphs below, the blue version shows content sooner, but the overall page load is slower. Thoughts?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this post, it answers your question in quite some detail I believe https://moz.com/blog/how-website-speed-actually-impacts-search-ranking

Answer (score 1):

The blue progress is better because it has a lower TTFB (time to first byte). This is extremely important as it tells search engines how many milliseconds it takes for one character to appear on the screen. According to page-speed insights documentation, it seems that any TTFB value of over 200ms is bad. The TTFB is also higher if your clients of your website are located 1/2 the earth's distance away. This can be proven by using webpagetest.org and testing your site from different countries.

The second nice thing about the blue progress (I'll name the website with this progress as the blue website from this point on) is that the results are more progressive sooner. If you rerun the exact same test again on webpagetest.org and look at the filmstrip for each site (using the finest timing resolution), you'll see that the blue website shows 25% of the content at 2.2 units (seconds?) then at about 4.0 units, more of the blue website loads. As for the red website, one has to wait 3.0 units before anything loads.

What I would suggest is to look to see what external resources are being loaded on your site and try to condense them into one to improve loading time. Also, try to reduce any back-end processing. For example, if you have a script with an extra long loop that runs before data is sent to the browser, try to reduce that long loop.